# jquery flip plugin on an axis

Tags: jquery, flip

i'm looking to make divs flip around like in this short animation i made with flash. [this flip](http://lab.smashup.it/flip) plugin looks pretty close to what i need, but the developer said it can't flip along the left axis like in my video. it only flips along the center.

also in flash i might've used a 3d tool to make it happen. 
[image]

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate would this help at all ?

Comment: yes i had considered CSS transforms, but a lot of the viewers will be on IE :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/), it lets you use CSS3 transforms and falls back to DirectX filters on IE! Pretty cool.

Comment: this looks very promising! i am looking into it now